# Audio Control in JavaFX WebKit?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, youtube

I've recently started using JavaFX for it's WebKit browser instead of the one found in SWT (because it doesn't support any current browsers).

The application I'm developing loads up a browser page that has a pre-generated youtube playlist that plays automatically. There's nothing wrong with the youtube player itself (as in when viewed on a regular browser).

However, every time the song finishes and loads the next one, the volume ignores the youtube settings and goes straight to 100%. If I click the volume meter again it fixes.

Here is the code used to display the given url:

```
final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

public Browser(String url) {
    getStyleClass().add("browser");
    webEngine.load(url);
    getChildren().add(browser);

}
```

Which gets wrapped in a JFXPanel:

```
private JFXPanel playerPanel;
    ....

    Browser b = new Browser("google.com/youtubeplayer/");
    Scene scene = new Scene(b, playerPanel.getWidth(), playerPanel.getHeight(), Color.web("#666970"));
    playerPanel.setScene(scene);
```

I did find a [similar question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246899/youtube-iframe-api-not-working-properly-in-javafx-webview), but there was no solution listed (other than the authors self edit which left no explanation).